# ¿como puedo dividir un Big Integer en java con un bucle for hasta llegar a su valor mínimo? empezando por 2 luego entre 3 etc.. hasta n?

Tags: java

1. public static void main(String[] args) {
       // create 3 BigInteger objects
       BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;

   ```
   // assign values to bi1, bi2
   bi1 = new BigInteger("9832324523532534423432423523423423425235342342342554534534552342344234234234234234233443432233244432");
   bi2 = new BigInteger("245232323234233242442787767676788787788878989789879879879898797879342334534");

   // assign gcd of bi1, bi2 to bi3
   bi3 = bi1.gcd(bi2);

   String str = "GCD of " + bi1 + " and " + bi2 + " is " + bi3;

   // print bi3 value
   System.out.println(str);
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema. podrias explicar mejor tu problema?